# maximum number of people that get a discount in O(nlogn+mlogm)

Tags: algorithm, greedy

**Question:**

suppose we have `n` people standing on line `x = 0`(none are standing in the same spot) and we have m stores on line `x = 1`.(none are located in the same spot). Every store gives a discount to the people who get to that store first. for example if three people get to one store at the same time before anyone else, all three of them get a discount. But if one of them gets there first and the other two after, only one gets a discount.

Each person chooses the nearest store to go to and everyone has the same speed. The question is to find a greedy algorithm that returns maximum number of people that get a discount and the stores each person must go to, to get that result in `O(nlogn+mlogm)`.

**my approach:**

Things get complicated if the stores are of equal distance from the person and this algorithm works. the only problem is that the order is `O(nlogn+mlogm+nlogm)`. I don't know how to improve it or if there are any better algorithms to use for this question so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematically, you can easily prove that:

```
O(n * log(n) + m * log(m)) = O(n * log(n) + m * log(m) + n * log(m))
```

Since that, for any n ∈ N*, any m ∈ N* the below inequality is true:

```
n * log(n) + m * log(m) + n * log(m) < 2 *(n * log(n) + m * log(m))
```

Which makes your solution fit with the expected complexity.